# What does this mean?: "pygame ImportError: No module named pygame"

Tags: android, pygame, kivy, qpython

"pygame ImportError: No module named pygame"

I get this on my Android Moto G phone when running a simple QPython script.
I should point out that this script used to work - so I suspect that QPython, Android, pygame, or something has taken an auto upgrade which has gone bad.

I tried to install pygame in the pip console, but it told me that pygame was already installed.

So, what's gone wrong !!! ????

Thanks.

Comment: this may help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317521/importerror-no-module-named-pygame

Comment: From your tag, are you trying to run a kivy app? This uses pygame as a backend on android, but in this case it's up to qpython to make sure it's available. I'd try reinstalling qpython if you haven't already, but if that doesn't work you'll probably have to look for qpython-specific solutions.

Comment: I can't reinstall QPython because I can only see QPython3, Not QPython2.7 . Unfortunately, QPython3 doesn't (yet) support kivy, so I have to use the 2.7 version.

Answer (score 1):

The shell is telling you it cannot find the module named "pygame"
The module "pygame" is either not installed or you have typed the name incorrectly.
Try reinstalling the pygame module

Comment: OK, I uninstalled pygame, using the QPython interface.

Comment: But, installing it now has a problem !

Comment: I'm using 'pip install pygame', but it's downloading "pygame-1.9.2pre-py2.7-macosx10.7.mpkg.zip" . That doesn't sound like the correct package for my Android Moto G phone !!!????

Comment: Oh, and by the way, I can't have typed pygame incorrectly - because it's not used in my simple script. It must be being used, though, by one of the imports, such as kivy or tkinter. This script used to work until something did an auto upgrade and broke things !!!