# Pygame not importing, tried all techniques

Tags: python, python-2.7, import, pygame, python-import

I have read some of the Stack Overflow posts here about pygame not importing. I have tried moving pygame in the scripts folder of Python, making sure it is the right type, and  installing it using anaconda prompt. Do you know why none of these are working? By the way, here's my code and error. I have Windows 10, 64 bit computer, and Python 2.7.

```
import sys, os, random, pygame
```

> ImportError: No module named pygame

Comment: If you've installed it with your anaconda prompt, you won't find it in your default Python installation.

Comment: I have moved it, and it didn't work.

Comment: You don't move the module, you install it: `pip install ...`

Comment: I have installed it

Comment: importing doesn't work

Comment: check the version used in your script `import sys`  `print(sys.version)`

Comment: 2.7.13 (v2.7.13:a06454b1afa1, Dec 17 2016, 20:53:40) [MSC v.1500 64 bit (AMD64)]

Comment: did you reinstall with pip since you moved the module ? any relevant message displayed ?

Comment: Yes, just said pygame already installed.

Comment: Is pygame in the correct folder?

Comment: Yes, it is.....................

Comment: and you already tried installing it with `conda install -c pygame`..?........`(AMD64)`....[ImportError: No module named 'pygame'](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23418392/1248974)

Comment: check `pip -V`  too to make sure

Comment: I just tried them, didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

make sure you installed the library in same python version where you are coding. if you don't know how to do that type this in python code and run it

```
import pip
pip.main(["install","pygame"])
```

if it does not work too you should probably upgrade python to 3.10

Answer (score -2):

some users arent run pygame command.after showing requirement message.if you download pygame copy that 2 folder named as"pygame"and"pygame-1.9.4.dist-info"socopy this folder to your"C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\Lib" seriously after that u r DONE!!!!!!!!