# My IDLE says Pygame has not been installed even though I have?

Tags: python, pygame

Whenever I run my code in the IDLE's shell, it always comes out with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\dELL\Desktop\MyProject\ReactionTimeProgram.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pygame
ImportError: No module named pygame
```

Is it telling me I haven't installed Pygame, because I have.

How can I fix this error?
Best Regards
RMR :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ImportError: No module named 'pygame'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317521/importerror-no-module-named-pygame)

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the proper version of python? When I run pygame with python2 instead of python3, that's what happens for me.

Comment: I'm running python 3.6.3 and it is still happening.