# How do you install the pygame module?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I'm currently using Python v3.7.3 32bit on win32. I cannot figure out how to install the Pygame module.

Whenever I import pygame it shows me this error:
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame`'

I searched for different tutorials on YouTube, but they end up confusing me! It would help me out if there is a step-by-step process to installing this module.
Thanks!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named 'pygame'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317521/importerror-no-module-named-pygame)

Comment: standard method `pip install pygame`. If you have two Python installed then you may install `PyGame` in one Python but import in other Python. Then you can use `python -m pip install pygame` to install in python which you use to run `python game.py`