# cant import pygame using vscode , python 3.8 , pygame installed from powershell

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, import, pygame

so im using visual code,
have python 3.8 installed and i installed the pygame package from powershell,
yet when im writing pygame code it gives me the next error:
**" ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame' "**
tried everything for hours cant get it to work
help will be apriciated <3
images:

[image]

Comment: Do you have multiple installations, or have you added and removed installations of python?

Comment: can you try running the code from command line with `python game.py`? Also, see my above comment.

Comment: See [ImportError: No module named 'pygame'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317521/importerror-no-module-named-pygame)

Answer (score 0):

What you also can do is to download [pygame](https://www.pygame.org/download.shtml) to your folder and than run the command python setup.py. This should install everythin correctly. If you still have trouble using pygame you can use the files in src_py from the download:

```
import init #instead of pygame.init()
```

I hope I was able to help.