# ModuleNotFoundError when importing Pygame after pip install Pygame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame, python-import, importerror

I was trying to make a simple snake game in Python so I installed Pygame using pip install Pygame. After I installed it successfully, I tried importing Pygame but I got this error:

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'

I'm new to python so I'm really stuck. I imported the module by the code.

```
import pygame
```

Comment: first check if it has been properly installed: do `pip freeze` and see if you can find the name of the package (be careful about pip and pip3 differences). then check if you have by mistake named any of your files as `pygame.py` because you shouldn't. if still got the problem, update your question by copying your import line here. maybe the way you call the library is wrong

Comment: A similar question has already been asked - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317521/importerror-no-module-named-pygame - try looking there.

Comment: I looked at the pip freeze and  I found it there then checked my files and none of the was named Pygame.py

Comment: Are you using virtualenv pyenv etc? What is your python version

Comment: I'm using python 3.8

Comment: Which IDE are you using? and what OS?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named 'pygame'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317521/importerror-no-module-named-pygame)

Comment: if never you use conda `conda install pygame` may help

Answer (score 2):

if you are on windows:

open cmd and then type:

```
    cd\

    cd /d C:\Windows

    cd /d C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\Scripts
```

and then type the command:

```
    pip install pygame
```

if you are on Mac:
just try `python -m pip install pygame`

if you are on linux:

```
    pip install pygame
```

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you install pygame to the 'venv' folder of your project if you're using pycharm or sublime. If you are using IDLE then open command prompt by holding: windows+R then searching cmd, or if you are on mac: cmd+space and search terminal.
then type `pip install pygame` for windows, and `python -m install pygame` for mac.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Pycharm and your stuck goto settings and then proceed to python interpreter you will see a page listing installed modules in your Pycharm project click the small plus sign and search for pygame after that click Install Package. If you still see an error message then repeat the steps, if that doesn't work try with internet connection.
I'm not good with Command Prompt but there's a way with it.
NOTE: I'm still a newbie in this area so I don't know if you'll consider my ideas useful    Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the python editor 'mu' it has pygame built in, no importing or anything, just use pygame commands like normal python commands

Comment: A solution that works with any editor would be better