# Import pygame doesn't work and instead it shows me an error message

Tags: python, pygame

This is the error it shows me when i simply write import pygame. Does anyone know whats wrong?

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-671b35b41eba> in <module>
----> 1 import pygame

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'
```

Comment: Have you installed pygame (pip install pygame)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named 'pygame'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317521/importerror-no-module-named-pygame)

Answer (score 0):

You need to pip install pygame by typing the following into your terminal: `pip install pygame`

You can then check the install using,
`pip show pygame`