# my pygame doesn't download; I get a traceback error

Tags: python, terminal, pygame

I'm trying to install pygame. I now need to type `import pygame` into the terminal, but then I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: No module named 'pygame'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317521/importerror-no-module-named-pygame)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this out,

1. Open Windows explorer
2. go to the python/scripts folder, where you've saved it.
3. Over there type cmd in the address bar and then a cmd window with the same directory will pop up
4. Now you need to go and again install pygame by the following command:

> C:\python34\scripts> python -m pip install pygame

5. Now, the final step is to check it out in your favorite ide by the command.

   ```
   import pygame
   print (pygame.ver)
   ```

if it works you're good to go.