# Pygame not importing

Tags: python, python-3.x, visual-studio-code, pygame

I've downloaded pygame version 2.1.2 and I'm using it with python 3.10.4 but it is giving an error when I try to import it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'
```

I have tried it on vscode and it was working but it suddenly isn't working anymore. Any suggestions please?

Comment: You said it was working and now it isn't working anymore. Did I get that correct? Maybe you have different Python versions on your computer and now you try to run your code with a Python version where PyGame isn't installed.

Comment: Have you installed that on a virtual environment before?

Comment: It is working now. I'm still not sure what happened but thanks for the suggestions

Answer (score 0):

Did you try install with pip like this: `python -m pip install pygame`?

Maybe you can find more answers on this page: [ImportError: No module named 'pygame'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18317521/importerror-no-module-named-pygame)

Comment: Just for the case of you are using virtualenv than it must be activated if you installed it in such place.
like 
# make the venv call it venv
python3 -m venv venv

# just checking what is there in global scope for pip3
pip3 list

# activate your local venv
source venv/bin/activate

# show local venv scope
pip3 list

than you could basicly install whatever you need in different versions... ;)